# Using conditionals to find words in strings

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to make a program that will help a user repair their phone depending on an input they type in

I have an issue where if someone were to answer that their screen is not working it will print the solution to two answers.

```
import string
punct = set(string.punctuation)

sentence = input('Please enter what is wrong with your phone ').lower()

sentence2 = ''.join(x for x in sentence if x not in punct)

if 'smashed' and 'screen' in sentence2:
    print ('Send your phone off for repairs')

if 'screen' and 'not' and 'working' in sentence2:
    print ('Charge your phone')
```

Here is my error:

[image]

Comment: The `in` operator only works one word at a time.  So for example, you want to check if `"smashed" in sentence2` and then if `"screen" in sentence2`, like `if "smashed" in sentence2  and "screen" in sentence2`.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into your post to make it easier for us to debug it

Comment: Please also copy and paste the program's output into your post. Screenshots of text are almost never appropriate.

Comment: A little bit aside, it sounds like you're trying to build a bot.  If so check out whats already out there, for example, https://www.fullstackpython.com/bots.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check that a set of key words are all found in a sentence, you need to use `if word1 in sentence and word2 in sentence`, or `if all(...)`:

```
diagnosis = {
    'Send your phone off for repairs': ['smashed', 'screen'],
    'Charge your phone': ['screen', 'not', 'working']
}
for solution, words in diagnosis.items():
    if all(word in sentence for word in words):
        print(solution)
```